# How to add style for every first list element, first children with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this markup:

```
<ul>
  <li> // this
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> // this
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my style i have this:

```
.main_menu ul > li {
   // some style
}
```

and that gives me some style for only first `li` in that tree, not for children `li` of it.
So, my question is how to set this with jQuery, when i'm trying with `$('.main_menu ul > li');` it doesn't work. I guess i need some kind of this write:

```
$('.main_menu ul').each().first().child();
```

but it's not correctly, can you help me?

Comment: I don't think this markup is correct you have li tag in another one

Comment: In your situation you should have 2 `UL` elements, i.e. `<ul><li><ul><li><div>...closing tags`.

Comment: ok, my mistake, i need to set this style for every li element but not for children of it

Comment: @djlukas777, can you rephrase your question? I think there are 10 answers that went straight to the junk now. Easy way is showing where the classes should be!

Comment: i know i'm idiot, now it's more clearly than my first entry

Comment: @djlukas777, that's `.main_menu > ul > li` selector; or, `$('.main_menu > ul > li').css(...)`. Why didn't this work?

Comment: where's your css class(main_menu) in html?

Comment: i have add up vote for your answer bc it's corect, thx, what can i say more?

Comment: you have to accept his answer as the "good one" with the tick-check button under the number.

Comment: sorry guys, my bad, thx all for help, u can close this theard it's  sucks

Comment: @djlukas777, sorry, I didn't understand you that my comment was correct. Just to doublecheck `.main_menu > ul > li` was the correct answer? I can add it as an answer below and you can tick it and close this question. Is that fine?

Comment: yeap, that solution solve my problem, much thx again, please do that

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure CSS3, though the support [is not complete.](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2)

Use the `:first-child` selector, this selects what you want.  `:first-child` [also works in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) so you can use it there.

`ul li:first-child` would select:

```
<ul>
  <li>             //this
    <li>
      <div></div>
    </li>
  </li>
  <li>             
    <li>
      <div></div>
    </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`>` selects all direct descendants, not just the first child. e.g:

`ul > li` would select:

```
<ul>
  <li>             //this
    <li>
      <div></div>
    </li>
  </li>
  <li>             // this
    <li>
      <div></div>
    </li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this adding also style for first-child children of first li

Comment: @djlukas777 Then you need to be clearer. If you only want the very first ul li, try this `ul:first-child > li:first-child`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this CSS selector:

```
.main_menu ul li:first-child {
   // some style
}
```

Should be no need for jQuery that way!

**Also**, as pointed out in the comments, your markup is wrong. Each nested `<li>` needs to wrapped in another `<ul>`, IE:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:first-child` selector, which selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

```
$('.main_menu ul li:first-child')
```

Documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.main_menu ul').first('li').css('border','1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$('.main_menu ul li').first().addClass('fancyClassOnFirstChild');`

or `$('.main_menu ul li:first-child').addClass('fancyClassOnFirstChild');`

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo selector called `:first-child` can select the first child of a element. This is a CSS selector and jQuery also supports it. So you can use it either by CSS or jQuery.

```
ul li:first-child {
   /* Your style */
}
```

or jQuery

```
$("ul li:first-child").css('style-name', 'property value');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working...

```
$('.main_menu ul li:first')
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.main_menu ul li:first-child {
   // some style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out,

```
$('.main_menu li:first').css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nJ2B3/)

```
$('ul').children('li').first().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `eq(0)` .You can do this . try this code :

```
$('.main_menu > ul').find('li:eq(0)').addClass('classname');
```